# Jumping numbers. The function must check the value with adjacent values

Tags: javascript

Create a function `isJumping` which has a number number and returns a line JUMPING if every digit in number differs from the neighbour by one. If condition is not realised, the line NOT JUMPING.

**Notes:**

> Input number is always positive
> The difference between 9 and 0 is not regarded like one
> All the numbers that contain only one digit - JUMPING

**Examples:**

```
isJumping(9) === 'JUMPING'
It's single-digit number

isJumping(79) === 'NOT JUMPING'
Adjacent digits don't differ by 1

isJumping(23454) === 'JUMPING'
Adjacent digits differ by 1
```

My not working code:

```
function isJumping(number) {

  let a = ''
  a = number.toString().split('');
  let finish = false

  for (let i = 0, j = 1, f = 2; i < a.length; i++, j++, f++) {
    if (i == 1) {
      finish = true
    }

    if (j < a.length && f < a.length) {
      if ((Number(a[j])+1) == Number(a[f]) && (Number(a[j])-1) == Number(a[f]-2)) {
        finish = 'JUMPING'
      } else  {
        finish = 'NOT JUMPING';
        break;
      }
   }
  }

  return finish
}

let number = 90
let numberNot = 1356

console.log(isJumping(number));
```

As you can already understand it is not working at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this -:

```
function isJumping(number) {
  let a = number.toString().split('');
  if(a.length === 1) return 'JUMPING';
  for(let i=1;i<a.length;i++){
     if(Math.abs(a[i]-a[i-1]) !== 1){
        return 'NOT JUMPING';
     }
  }
  return 'JUMPING';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My code:
function isJumping(number) {
let str = String(number);

```
let difference = 0;

for (let i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
    difference = str[i] - str[i - 1];
    if (difference !== 1 && difference !== -1) {
        return 'NOT JUMPING';
    }
}
return 'JUMPING';
```

}

Comment: You should include a description of the solution and ensure all your code is in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to convert the number to a string to use the loop 'for' to check all numbers. Then we check the difference between them. Please look at the code snippet below.

```
    function isJumping(number) {
    const str = String(number);

    for (let i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(Math.abs(str[i] - str[i-1]) !== 1) {
    return 'NOT JUMPING';    
    }
   }
    return 'JUMPING';
   }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.